# SQL Trouble Getting output

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query seems to run without any issue, but there is no output from my database.

```
SELECT 
    Salaries.playerID
FROM   
    Teams
INNER JOIN 
    Salaries ON  Teams.teamID = Salaries.teamID
WHERE  
    (Salaries.salary > (SELECT MIN(Salaries.salary)
                        FROM Salaries
                        INNER JOIN Teams ON Salaries.teamID = Teams.teamID
                        WHERE (Teams.name = 'Boston Red Sox')
                        GROUP BY Teams.name)
    )
    AND (Teams.name = 'Yankees')
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output please, and someone might just throw a query with different syntax that works.

Comment: Can you share data for these two team? 
1. Boston Red Sox
2. Yankees

Comment: I think you should change `MIN(Salaries.salary)` to `MIN(salary)` ;).

Comment: Sample Output

rodrial01 $33,990,000.00
rodrial01 $33,000,000.00
rodrial01 $32,000,000.00

Comment: I don't think you need or actually want the group by teams.name part but not familiar with sql-server syntax. Also, I'd suggest running the queries piece meal and adding on the additional where statements one by one to see which one specifically is causing a null result. It could simply be a name issue where the name you are equaling doesn't exist or is misspelled, or it could be that in your DB there isn't a player on the yankees with a salary greater than the min salary on the red sox. Being able to see your tables as others have asked would go a long way towards helping find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the table with data like `image-1` below images then output will be as `image-2`

**image-1**
[image]

**image-2**
[image]